# Reinitialize Masonry / Isotope after pressing href #/

Tags: php, html, jquery-isotope, masonry

I am having some troubles with Masonry not beeing initialized. My divs have different heights, so I am using Masonry and Isotope to make them show correctly. All these divs have the class `.item`

Please see site: http://www.dokfilm.no/ and scroll down to *Nyhende*.

By pressing either *Nyhende* or the *Plus icon*. You can see that the divs are being loaded above each other. Also they are pushed to the back of the page. This is because Masonry is not beeing initialized when pressing the link.

[image: Masonry error not being activated]

If you resize the window of the browser you will see that Masonry is being reinitilized and all items are moving themselves directly to the correct positions.

[image: Masonry being loaded correctly]

The problem is that Masonry is not being reinitilized by the following:

```
<a href="#/ "title="Artiklar" data-target="#" class="nodec">
   <div class="expander">
        <?php echo '<h1>' . esc_html__( 'Nyhende', 'dokfilm' ) . '</h1>'; ?>
        <img class="open" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/plus.png" alt="Open">
        <img class="close" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/minus2.png" alt="Close" />
   </div>
</a>
```

Here is more PHP if needed. artikler2.php is where the posts are being loaded.

**PHP**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <a id="artikler"></a>
    <section id="artikler" class="section artikler">
        <div class="blacktext">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12 solidborderned bittelittpaddingoppned littpaddingned bittelittluft">
                    <a href="#/ "title="Artiklar" data-target="#" class="nodec">
                        <div class="expander">
                            <?php echo '<h1>' . esc_html__( 'Nyhende', 'dokfilm' ) . '</h1>'; ?>
                            <img class="open" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/plus.png" alt="Open">
                            <img class="close" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/minus2.png" alt="Close" />
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <div id="event-info" class="text littluft">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">                             
                                <?php include 'artikler2.php' ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<div id="isotope-list">
        <div class="row">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>               
        <div class="item col-md-6 littluft"> 

                <div class="black content grid lefttext maximg littluft">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('event_thumb'); } ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="red padding">
                        <h2 class="whitetext nomargin"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <span class="whitetext thin"> 
                            <?php the_time('j. F Y') ?>
                        </span><br/>
                        <span class="whitetext thin">
                            <?php
                                $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );
                                $content = preg_replace('/<[\/]?b>/i', '', $content);
                                $content_parts = get_extended( $content );
                                echo $content_parts['main'];
                            ?>
                        </span>
                        <div class="whitelink"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Les mer</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </a> 

        </div>
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**PHP Footer**

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>

(function( $ ) {

    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: '.item',
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    });

    //Reinitialize masonry inside each panel after the relative tab link is clicked - 
    $('a[data-toggle=tab]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.on('shown.bs.tab', function () {

            $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
                $container.masonry({
                    columnWidth: '.item',
                    itemSelector: '.item'
                });
            });

        }); //end shown
    });  //end each

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Isotope.js

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Looking forward to hear from you,

Comment: I get `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/` on console. `Artiklar` anchors have wrong format of href attribute. Can you fix these for better debugging. I believe after this fix you code will work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Fixed the problem, but still the same error.

Comment: You have both isotope.pkgd.min.js(old version) and masonry.pkgd.min.js loaded on the site. As you know, they are not used together. The Nyhende items are being effected by isotope code, not masonry code posted. The items are in `<div id="isotope-list"></div>` which is acted on by the code in isotope.js `var $container = $('#isotope-list');  
 $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry' }); });`. Might want to post that code instead. Also, you have 2 versions of jQuery loaded, not a good idea for sure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will add the code in isotope.js above.

Comment: there is still, at least, one error in console, after clicking on a + `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=]`. Also check

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Removed the syntax error and did some changes. However, masonry / isotope is still not being loaded correctly. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding an `id` to the link. Then I replaced the class `isotope-list` with `masonry-container`. Then I added a function in the footer that reloaded masonry.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Artikler" data-target="#" data-toggle="tab" class="nodec" id="nyhendeartiklar">
     <div class="expander">
          <?php echo '<h1>' . esc_html__( 'Nyhende', 'dokfilm' ) . '</h1>'; ?>
          <img class="open" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/plus.png" alt="Open">
          <img class="close" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/minus2.png" alt="Close" />
     </div>
</a>



<div id="event-info" class="text littluft">
      <div class="row masonry-container">
            <div class="col-md-12">                             
                  <!-- Loop comes here -->
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery in footer:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#nyhendeartiklar", function() {
  $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry();
    });
});
```